# Language Recommendations To Upscale a Process Heavy PHP & MySQL App

Tags: php, python, mysql, c

Currently I run an online platform that collects various technical data and stores it in a MySQL table.  After a set time, a process is run (currently a PHP script) that analyzes the data and calculates a new data set to store in a different table.

The current system works, and I have optimized it well over the past several months.  My question is in regards to a scaling issue that is creeping up.

As the platform grows, there is more initial data collected.  The script is taking longer to complete.  At this rate, I'm sure there will be a time that PHP will fail through either a timeout or too much memory being used.

I have considered re-writing the script in Python, however I am reading that MySQL paired with Python would be even slower.  Would coding a native app in C with a wrapper in PHP be a better option to pair with MySQL? Generally what is the next step from simple PHP / MYSQL when it's time to upscale a process heavy application?

Comment: The answer is going to be very dependent on the task you're doing in PHP. Can you give a bit more info about the task, specifically?

Comment: PHP currently loops through all the new entries in the first table, performs a dozen or so operations using the data, then writes the new figures to a second table.  The time increments between when the script is able to run is not changeable (ie: I cannot split each execution into smaller 'chunks' to lighten the load)

Comment: Don't know if it would help you or not, but have you considered using multi-threaded PHP with each run? https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to scaling issues and mathematical computation, Python is the preferred language -- see http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/php-vs-python-analysis/

If you really need to optimize the "number crunching" part of the code, you can write it in C and call it from Python.

When dealing with bulk data processing, there many methods (too many to discuss here). Communicating with MySQL usually isn't the issue, and Python isn't any slower at making SQL queries and getting responses.

The next step is to write a Python process to do exactly the same task as the PHP process and get some benchmark times, and then work on optimizing the process.